# Remove second appearence of a substring from string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

I need to remove the second appearance of a substring from the main string, IF both substrings are next to each other. e.g.:

`Jhon\Jhon\Jane\Mary\Bob` needs to end `Jhon\Jane\Mary\Bob`

but `Mary\Jane\Mary\Bob` has to remain unchanged.

Can anyone can come out with a performant way to do this?

'\' is the separator of different names, so it can be use as limit of the substring to replace.

**EDIT**: this is to be run on a SELECT statement, so it should be a one line solution, I can't use variables.
Also, if the names are repetaed anywhere else, I have to let them there. Only remove one occurrence if both the first and the second names are the same.

Comment: Do you want SQL Server to do this, or do you want it to be fast? Short of CLR I don't think it will be possible to do both. You can do this with a splitting UDF but it won't be fast on a large result set. I think you will be better off performing the string operations at the client where the language better supports it and you will be looping here anyway...

Comment: @AaronBertrand I want it all! The result of the SP this is in is a report sent to the client, which just transforms it into a csv file, so I can't do that... on the other hand, the report can have 200K rows, I'm not sure if that's too much or not...

Comment: @AlejoBrz There are a lot of good ETL tools out there that can do this. SSIS is one and it comes with SQL server. Using a report as an ETL tool is not the way to go.

Comment: Surely whatever is writing the report output to the CSV file could also parse each line and perform modifications to it as it's writing each line to the file. Also what do you want to do with `Jhon\Jhon\Jhon\Jane\Mary\Bob`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I only have to remove the first duplicated name. It SHOULDN'T appear a third time, but if it does I have to leave it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go for string manipulation. I thought it'd take longer to execute the query, but testing it in... ejem... production environment... ejem... I found out that it did not (much to my surprise). It ain't pretty, I know, but it's easy to mantain...

Here is a simplified version of my final query:

```
SELECT SOQ.PracticeId,
       CASE WHEN LEFT(SOQ.myString, SOQ.SlashPos) = SUBSTRING(SOQ.myString, SOQ.SlashPos + 1, LEN(LEFT(SOQ.myString, SOQ.SlashPos)))
            THEN RIGHT(SOQ.myString, LEN(SOQ.myString) - SOQ.SlashPos)
            ELSE SOQ.myString
       END as myString
  FROM (SELECT OQ.AllFields, OQ.myString, CHARINDEX('\', OQ.myString, 0) as SlashPos
          FROM MyOriginalQuery OQ) SOQ
```

Answer (score 2):

So here is one try, but as I said, I don't think you will get a *fast* solution in native T-SQL.

First, if you don't already have a numbers table, create one:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @UpperLimit int = 4000;

;WITH n AS
(
    SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
)
SELECT [Number] = rn - 1
INTO dbo.Numbers FROM n
WHERE rn <= @UpperLimit + 1;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX n ON dbo.Numbers([Number]);
```

Then create two functions. One that splits strings apart into a table, and then another that re-joins the results of the first function but ignores any subsequent duplicates.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
    @List  nvarchar(4000),
    @Delim char(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN ( SELECT 
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim)),
      [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
      CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
      FROM dbo.Numbers
      WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
      AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], 1) = @Delim
    );
GO
```

Second function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RebuildString
(
    @List  nvarchar(4000),
    @Delim char(1)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ( SELECT newval = STUFF((
     SELECT @Delim + x.[Value] FROM dbo.SplitStrings(@List, @Delim) AS x
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SplitStrings(@List, @Delim) AS x2
      ON x.rn = x2.rn + 1
      WHERE (x2.rn IS NULL OR x.value <> x2.value)
      ORDER BY x.rn
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'')
    );
END
GO
```

Now you can try it against the two samples you gave in your question:

```
;WITH cte(colname) AS
(
    SELECT 'Jhon\Jhon\Jane\Mary\Bob'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Mary\Jane\Mary\Bob'
)
SELECT dbo.RebuildString(colname, '\')
FROM cte;
```

Results:

```
Jhon\Jane\Mary\Bob
Mary\Jane\Mary\Bob
```

But I strongly, strongly, strongly recommend you thoroughly test this against your typical data size before deciding to use it.

Comment: +1 for such an elavorate response! I decided to go with string manipulation though for ease of mantainence, and I tried the report using it and it proved not to increase response time.