# Compare two string column and result in third column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, compare

I have following table with three columns containing the string values.

```
ID       strOriginal                  strNew                 strFinal
1        '122,234,23,22,554'          '23,22'               '122,234,554'
2        '122,23,22,554,998,856,996'  '554,998,856,996'     '122,23,22'
3        '60,89,65,87,445,54'         '87'                  '60,89,65,445,54'
```

Now in last column i need to compare two columns values and get result values in strFinal column which has all the values of strOriginal column except strNew values.

Can anyone suggest me how to do it in SQL?

Comment: Who generates this table? If you have control over it, you might consider having two tables Orig and New each with and ID (not a pk) and a str column. This would be easier to manage in SQL and you just use except for this query

Comment: @Dan i know that but i want result in same table in same row. Actually i did this table after processing on multiple tables and then i got this result in final table.

Comment: It depends on version of SQL Server. And also could strNew contain not nearby number? E.g. for `ID = 1 and strNew = '23,554'` which gives `strFinal = '122,234,22'`.

Comment: One comment: this is not a normalized DB structure... Restructure it while (or if you still...) can...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below query :

```
select *,
case when patindex('%'+STRNEW+'%',STRORIGINAL)>=1 
     then replace(replace (STRORIGINAL,STRNEW,''),',,',',') 
     else STRORIGINAL 
end final_String
from table1
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6682a/13)**

Answer (score 0):

Well below is the link which might be helpful. 
[Remove second appearence of a substring from string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458473/remove-second-appearence-of-a-substring-from-string-in-sql-server)

However, in this link strings are delimited by '/' where you can substitute ',' and also slight modification is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try below, first replace the table name([Table_3]) with your one.

```
 DECLARE @S      varchar(max),
         @S1     varchar(max),
         @Split  char(1),
         @X      xml,
         @X1     xml;

  SET @Split = ',';

  SELECT @S  = [strOriginal] FROM [Table_3] Where id=2;  
  SELECT @S1 = [strNew] FROM [Table_3] Where id=2;

  SELECT @X = 
  CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s> ' + REPLACE(@S,@Split,'</s> <s>') + ' </s> </root> ')

  SELECT @X1 = 
  CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s> ' + REPLACE(@S1,@Split,'</s> <s>') + ' </s> </root> ')

  Select * From 
   (
      SELECT [Value] = LTrim(T.c.value('.','varchar(20)'))
      FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
   ) 
   As CollectionVal
   Where [Value] Not In 
   (
      SELECT [Value1] = LTrim(T1.c1.value('.','varchar(20)'))
      FROM @X1.nodes('/root/s') T1(c1)
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that will turn the CSV values into tables (see [this post](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/20009) for a good example of this)

Then, set up a trigger to automatically update the third column on INSERT / UPDATE

```
CREATE TRIGGER INS_TempData
   ON  TempData
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    --This will ONLY work against a single row at a time.  It will need to be modified to work with bulk operations
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --Declare are placeholders
    DECLARE @original varchar(200)
    DECLARE @new varchar(200)
    DECLARE @final varchar(200)
    DECLARE @id int
    --Populate our variables with the inserted values
    SELECT @id = id, @Original = stroriginal, @new = strnew FROM INSERTED   
    SELECT @final = SUBSTRING(
    (SELECT ',' + a.value from [dbo].[UTILfn_Split](@original,',') a
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[UTILfn_Split](@new,',') b on a.value = b.value
    --Eliminate the strNew values from the result
    WHERE b.value IS NULL
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),2,200000) 
    --Update the table with the final value
    UPDATE TempData SET strFinal = @final where id = @id
END
GO
```

*NOTE: Change `TempData` to the name of your table*

Then, when you insert new data

```
INSERT INTO TEMPDATA(STRORIGINAL, STRNEW) VALUES ('122,234,23,22,554' ,'23,22')
```

`StrFinal` will automatically be populated with `122,234,554`